# map-reduce for sorting

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a collection whose documents have the following structure:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("XXXX"),
  "data" : "stuff",
  "type" : "X",
  "location" : [XX, XX],
  "datetime" : {stuff},
  "user" : 453,
  "userName" : "XXX",
  "timestamp" : XXXX,
  "device" : XXXX
}
```

I need to know which device uses each user.

Since each document is a log entry there can be a lot per user. So what I need to do is to aggrupate them per user.

I am doing this in php rigth now, but it takes to long, there are about 2k users and 60k logs so I think using map-reduce would be the best option for this.

I dont quite understand map reduce, im just getting started. Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a simple aggregate.

```
 db.yourcollection.aggregate([

    {$match : { user : 453}},
    {$group : {_id : "$user", devices: {$push : "$device"}}}
]);
```

This will return all the devices(saved in an array called devices) for user 453.